# Как запретить программное свертывание(не закрытие) приложения?

Tags: winapi

то есть, что бы не зависимо от посылаемых ему сообщений, оно все же не сворачивалось?
 1. В случае, если это мое приложение(есть исходники)
 2. Если приложение чужое(нет исходников).
может, что то из WinAPI? или создание спец. резидентной службы для мониторинга?

Comment: может как-то это событие можно перехватить? (недопустить)?

Answer (score 1):

если приложение ваше то смотрите события формы.
Если приложение чужое то мониторьте состояние и отсылайте сообщение на разворачивание окна.

Comment: разворачивание чужого не подходит, потому как окошко будет скакать туда-сюда, а это значит, что работать с ним будет невозможно.

Comment: а как вы сможете окну запретить обработать системное сообщение?
ставит глобальный хук, ловить все сообщения, пропуская через себя фильтровать на само сообщение и на то какому окну оно направлено.

Напишите зачем это вам, может есть решение более красивое.

Answer (score 0):

Помню как отмена закрытия работает. В событии OnClose добавляется функция с оператором cancel();

Честно говоря я не помню точно как писалось, но думаю как то аналогично.

Ну а раз приложение не ваше - нужно запускать через самописный ланчер с перехватом сообщения, либо дописывать этот функционал.